# Нахождение одностороннего ряда

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть двумерный массив чаров. Мне надо найти в этом массиве определенные получившиеся "слова" в процессе. С условием, что слова могут идти только в некоторых направлениях: слева направо, сверху вниз, по диагонали вниз направо и по диагонали вверх направо. В другие стороны получившиеся слова не надо учитывать.
С каждым добавлением символа в массив, мне надо узнать, получилось ли слово? Если да, то в определенной последовательности записать координаты ячеек в массив

Как реализовать данный алгоритм? Если что я это делаю для своей игры (а то будут говорить еще что для школы задачки не решаем)

У меня есть одна идея, но боюсь есть лучше, да и реализация в коде не ясна, поэтому и пишу сюда. При добавлении символа, мы знаем координату добавления. Поэтому мы можем пройтись по 4-м осям и все их "просканировать" на образования слов

Comment: Где ты хранишь слова для сравнения?

Comment: @RomanIeromenko В стринговом листе

Comment: Что значит "получилось ли слово"? У вас есть некий словарь, в котором надо искать? Что вы подразумеваете под словом в двумерном массиве? Любую последовательность символов или они чем-то в начале и в конце должны быть ограничены (пробелом, например, или границей массива)?

Comment: Мне кажется, пахнет рекурсией

Comment: @АндрейNOP Слово - последовательность символов по тем осям, которая совпадает с любой последоательностью из словаря. Слово ничем не ограниченно

Comment: Ну а какова ваша идея-то? Запускаете цикл по массиву. Для каждой ячейки по очереди запускаете 4 цикла по своим направлениям (пока есть куда идти) и на каждом шаге ищете получившееся слово в своем списке.

Comment: Строите граф по вашим данным, где узел - ячейка массива, ребро - ход вправо/верх и тд. Ваше слово тоже выглядит как граф - если соединить буквы как узлы. В итоге задача сводится к поиску подграфа в графе.

Comment: @tym32167, с графом не понятно. Вот есть у меня ячейка-вершина, она соединена ещё с восемью такими же (ну пусть с четырьмя, ориентированный граф), как нам на каждом шаге выбрать ребро, соответствующую направлению? Или для каждого направления строить отдельный граф? Тогда смысла в них вообще не будет...

Comment: Автор, уточните, слова могут располагаться только строго по прямой или могут собираться по ломаной линии?

Comment: @АндрейNOP У нас есть слово. Слово - это порядок букв, то есть вершин. Берем первую букву слова - ищем все узлы с этой буквы в большом графе с поля. Нашли вершины для 1й буквы слова, ищем среди них те, которые соединены со второй буквой слова, потом с третьей и тд до конца слова. Если дошли до конца слова - слово на доске есть. Не дошли - нет

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот вам псевдокод, описывающий алгоритм:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
    {
        // Идем вправо
        строка = поле[row, column];
        int d = 1;
        while (column + d < columns)
        {
            строка = строка + поле[row, column + d];
            ПоискСтрокиВСловаре(строка);
            d++;
        }
        // Идем вниз
        // Аналогичный код, граничное условие (row + d < rows)

        // Идем по диагонали вниз
        // Аналогичный код, граничное условие (column + d < columns && row + d < rows)

        // Идем по диагонали вверх
        // Аналогичный код, граничное условие (column + d < columns && row - d >= 0)
    }
}
```

Дальнейшие оптимизации:

- Запомнить минимальную и максимальную длину слов в словаре и выходить при ее достижении;
- На текущем шаге проверять не только целиком слово, но и наличие слов, начинающихся с текущей подстроки;
- Продумать эффективный способ хранения словаря (в виде дерева, возможно);
- При добавлении новой буквы искать не целиком по всему полю, а только по строкам, столбцам и диагоналям, на которых лежит добавленная буква.

Comment: А если микс - шаг вправо, шаг вниз, шаг вправо?

Comment: А так можно? Я думаю, что слова можно собирать только по прямым линиям, как в кроссворде

Comment: @tym32167, подождем что скажет автор

Comment: Ну да, ток по прямым линиям. Ряд же)

Comment: Ты будешь зубчатый массив использовать для получения результатов? Думаю надо его строковый, в первом индексе слова, а далее - последовательность типа 1,2 ; 3,4 то есть координаты начального

Comment: @RomanIeromenko я верно понял, вы предлагаете координаты писать в строки и потом, при необходимости их читать, парсить строки обратно?

Comment: Да, вообщем-то это один из вариантов хранения, конечно немножко затратненько